# How to deploy Codeignator- 4.1.3 using Oauth2.0 Restful API into the cPanel server?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth-2.0

While I'm deploying codeignator-4.1.3 using Oauth2.0 restful API project it's deployed successfully but when I try to use login Authentication.
I got an error.

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Client credentials were not found in the headers or body"
}
```

And I also pass all the header data with client_ID & client_secret key.

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\Admin;
use \App\Libraries\Oauth;
use App\Models\UserModel;
use \OAuth2\Request;
use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;

Header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); //for allow any domain, insecure
Header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *'); //for allow any headers, insecure
Header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'); //method allowed

class User extends ResourceController
{
use ResponseTrait;

public function login(){
 $oauth = new Oauth();
 $request = new Request();
 $respond = $oauth->server->handleTokenRequest($request->createFromGlobals());
 $code = $respond->getStatusCode();
 $body = $respond->getResponseBody();
 return $this->respond(json_decode($body), $code );
}


}
```

App\Libraries\oauth2

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;

//use \OAuth2\Storage\Pdo;
use \App\Libraries\CustomOauthStorage;
class Oauth{

var $server;

   function __construct(){
    $this->init();
}

public function init(){
$dsn = getenv('database.default.DSN');
$username = getenv('database.default.username');
$password = getenv('database.default.password');

$storage = new CustomOauthStorage([
                    'dsn' => $dsn,
                    'username' => $username,
                    'password' => $password
                    
                   ]);
$this->server = new \OAuth2\Server($storage);
$this->server->addGrantType(new \OAuth2\GrantType\UserCredentials($storage));


}


}
```

.env

```
database.default.hostname = localhost
database.default.database = db_restapi
database.default.username = demo@demo.in
database.default.password = demo@1234
database.default.DBDriver = MySQLi
database.default.DSN =mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_restapi;
```

.htaccess

RewriteEngine on

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

</IfModule>

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

My coding is successfully running on a local server but when I deploy it on cPanel, I face some errors, which I mention above. Kindly resolve this issue.

Comment: please share your code and what you have tried. also include the relevant bits of your file instead of linking to external sites or images. also, please properly format your post.

Comment: Where are the client credentials in the headers?

Comment: screenshot. Controller[1]: i.stack.imgur.com/vQLCp.jpg App\Libraries\oauth2\.[2]: i.stack.imgur.com/PTnfu.jpg .env/ [3]: i.stack.imgur.com/d0X0x.jpg .htaccess/ [4]: i.stack.imgur.com/fiTsy.jpg My coding is successfully running on a local server but when I deploy it on cPanel, I face some errors, which I mention above. Kindly resolve this issue

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or any other text. Please use [edit] link instead of posting information in the comments.

Comment: @JamesZ Thanks for suggesting me, can you check it I updated